# Python, Tkinter. Dynamic image placement issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

AS the title says i'm using Tkinter in python 3.0.

I've made a small GUI that is supposed to have a small logo in the bottom right that moves with the window as it changes size.

I've had the icon appear when i use static values and have it move around the screen with relx and rely. my goal is for the picture to be ~ 50 pixels from the bottom right of the window regardless of the window size.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
root.title("Test")
root.geometry("500x500")
root.config(bg = "#2b8cc0")

WindowHeight = root.winfo_height()
WindowWidth = root.winfo_width()


def button():
    print("The width of Tkinter window:", (root.winfo_width()-250)/root.winfo_width())
    print("The height of Tkinter window:", (root.winfo_width()-250)/root.winfo_width())


logo = PhotoImage(file = r"File path")
img = Label(root,image = logo)
img.place(relx = (root.winfo_width()-250)/root.winfo_width() , rely = (root.winfo_height()-250)/root.winfo_height())

button1 = tk.Button(root,text= "print position",
                    fg = "white", 
                    bg ="#08437f",
                    font= "Helvetica",
                    command= lambda: button())
```

Comment: If you use `.winfo_X()` calls to set the coordinates, they're guaranteed to be wrong after the window is resized.  However, you can do what you want with static values - `relx=1.0, x=-50, rely=1.0, y=-50` I think.

Comment: The x and y are the size of the image plus 50 (250 in this case), but this has worked a treat, thank you very much. I didn't realise you could use a combination of relx and x.